# Como fazer um update no Node.js e Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
{
    "_id": "58fe27e0e340671c9859c995",
    "__v": 0,
    "form": [
    {
        "_id": "58fe2b1de437791cd02b9a8c",
        "sections": [
            {
                "_id": "58fe2b1de437791cd02b9a8d",
                "input": {
                    "_type": "radio"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "58fe2ca32470711c586d6b6e",
        "sections": []
    }
    ]
}

var save = function(req, res) {
    var survey = {};
    survey.id = req.params.surveyId; // 58fe27e0e340671c9859c995
    survey.form_id = req.params.formId; // 58fe2b1de437791cd02b9a8c
    survey.newObj = req.body.sections; // [{ input: {_type: 'checkbox'}}]

    Survey.update(
        { _id: survey.id }, // 58fe27e0e340671c9859c995 
        {$set:
        {'form': { _id: survey.form_id , sections: survey.newObj } }
        },
        {safe: true, upsert: true},
        function(err, model) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(model);
        }
    );
};
```

Eu gostaria de substituir o que há dentro do array de objetos (`sections`) inteiro por um novo array de objetos: `[{ input: {_type: 'checkbox'}}]` na posição de `_id: 58fe2b1de437791cd02b9a8c`

a minha function save não está funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você está tentando atualizar um array (form) dentro de um array (sections), certo?

Para isso tem que usar o operador posicional ($). Não conheço mongoose ou node.js, consigo te ajudar no mongoshell: a atualização ficaria assim (assumindo que a collection seja "survey"):

```
db.survey.update({"_id":"58fe27e0e340671c9859c995", "form._id" : "58fe2b1de437791cd02b9a8c"} ,{$set : {"form.$.sections" : [{ input: {_type: 'checkbox'}}]}})
```

Lembrando que a opção de upsert não vai funcionar com o operador posicional, o documento precisa existir no banco para que a consulta acima funcione corretamente.

Pelo que ví no código é só substituir os parâmetros no teu método/função.